# MSBuild Tools 2019 not showing up in dropdown list in Teamcity

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, teamcity, devops

I have two Teamcity servers: agent & server

Current teamcity version installed: 2018.1.3 (build 58658)

Both server & agent server have installed:

- Visual Studio Community 2017: 15.9.28

  Visual Studio Build Tools 2017: 15.9.27

  Visual Studio Community 2019: 16.7.6

  Visual Studio Build Tools 2019: 16.7.6

I recently installed 2019 versions on both servers to have MSBuild version 16 to be available for my builds. However, even after restarting the agents. Server just wont pickup the changes, Im still looking at my 2017 options in my MSBuild setting dropdowns.

[MSBuild Step config (click here to see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nv5Z.png)

What am I missing here? How do I make my MS Build tools 2019 to show up in Teamcity?

More background info:
Devs are getting this in teamcity when attempting to build. Thinking MSBuild 16 might do the trick?

```
Feature 'default literal' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.1 or greater.
```

PS:
I definitely need to do some work on this TC setup. There's a lot to be done as you can see, starting with my outdated version of TC. But this issue is on my top list for the moment. Im also fairly new to TC, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to update your TC version to at least 2019.1.

From this [support request](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008320759-Visual-Studio-2019-Support):

> Denis Lapuente, May 25, 2020 03:54:
>
> VS 2019 support was introduced in the 2019.1 release:
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-59392
>
> Since TeamCity 2018.2 itself is out of support, we would strongly
> recommend upgrading.

Comment: And indeed, upgrading to 2019.1. TeamCity is now able to recognize MSBuild 16. Thanks again.